# Convert PartialView to HTML

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, json, partial-views

I am just wondering if it is possible to convert

```
PartialView("_Product", model)
```

to **html** so we can send it back with **JSON** ?

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Absolutely, put the following method in a shared controller or a helper class.  It will return the rendered view in HTML, the usage is self explainatory:

```
public static string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

    using (var sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, new TempDataDictionary(), sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: U are awesome genius man! :)

Comment: @Leo Nix How should I create the context argument? I tried to initialize an instance but I don't know the ControllerBase argument of its constructor.

Comment: you don't need to create one if you use it in the context a controller action: ControllerContext is a property of the controller so just pass it in.   https://goo.gl/pp5AkR

Comment: Say you're trying to render a partial view in HTML rather than calling it from the controller. Then what do you use as the context? e.g. `<script> var viewHtml = @Helpers.RenderViewToString(???, "~/Views/MyView.cshtml", null);`  You don't have access to the ControllerContext from the View.

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if it is best practice or not, but if you left it as it is

```
return PartialView("_Product", model)
```

Then you can call the method using AJAX:

```
$.ajax ({
  type: "POST",
        url: _url,
        data: _data,
        success: function (result) {
            // the result is the returned html from the partial view
        }
})
```